# How should I structure a generic React/Typescript form component whose fields can be passed in as a type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, ecmascript-6

My application has a number of similar edit forms for a number of different kinds of items. Rather than writing a different form component for each kind of item, I want to write a generic component that can take a type/interface and then display a series of inputs based on that type.

I've tried to use typescript's generics syntax along with index signature syntax to achieve what I want. I've specified a generic type "T" that extends a type that can be indexed by string and returns a string, and then specified the generic type as the component's state. However, when I try to assign a string to state, I get an error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[string]'.

Here is the code:

```js
    type DataType {
        [index: string]: string
    }

    interface EditFormProps<T> {
        initialState: T,
        someCallback: (item: T) => any1,
    }

    export default class EditForm<T extends DataType> extends React.Component<EditFormProps<T>, T> {
        constructor(props: any) {
            super(props)
            this.state = props.initialState
        }

        someOtherFunction(someAttribute: string, someString: string) {
            this.setState({
                [someAttribute]: someString,    // Here is where I get the error above.
            })
        }
    }
```

Instantiated like this:

```js
    interface Foo extends DataType {
        foo: string,
        bar: string,
    }

    ...

    import Foo from 'Foo'
    import EditForm from 'EditForm'
    class EditFooForm extends EditForm<Foo> {}

    ...

    <EditFooForm
        initialState={{foo: "", bar: ""}}
        someCallback={(item: Foo) => {}}
    />
```

Question 1: Given that generic type T is guaranteed to return a string when indexed with a string, and component state is typed as T, why is typescript complaining when I assign a string to state?

Question 2: Is my problem more broadly that this whole approach is inadvisable? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Your `EditForm` is not generic, it's designed to work only with `DataType`. So make it `EditForm extends React.Component<EditFormProps<DataType>, DataType>`

Comment: @zerkms I'm a little confused, this way I can't specify a type at all? I've edited my post to reflect the instantiation, I pass in a type that extends DataType but has specific fields.

Comment: Right, in that case I'm not sure I can suggest anything, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem lies in the type definition of `someAttribute`:

```
    someOtherFunction(someAttribute: string, someString: string) {
        this.setState({
            [someAttribute]: someString,    // Here is where I get the error above.
        })
```

You use `someAttribute` which is a `string` to index into an instance of `T`. A string is not a valid indexer for `T`.

I think you should be able to fix this using the `keyof` keyword

```
    someOtherFunction(someAttribute: keyof T, someString: string) {
```

This way, you have restricted `someAttribute` to only have values that are valid indexers for `T`.